# calculate mean using 'year + month' combination in xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netcdf file with daily data for 5 years (2011 to 2015). I want to calculate monthly averages for the data using XArray in Python.

```
netcdf file:////test/Combined.nc {
  dimensions:
    latitude = 681;
    longitude = 841;
    time = 1826;
  variables:
    double latitude(latitude=681);
      :_FillValue = NaN; // double
      :name = "latitude";
      :long_name = "latitude";
      :units = "degrees_north";
      :standard_name = "latitude";

    double longitude(longitude=841);
      :_FillValue = NaN; // double
      :name = "longitude";
      :long_name = "longitude";
      :units = "degrees_east";
      :standard_name = "longitude";

    long time(time=1826);
      :name = "time";
      :long_name = "time";
      :standard_name = "time";
      :units = "days since 2011-01-01 00:00:00";
      :calendar = "proleptic_gregorian";

    float PET(time=1826, latitude=681, longitude=841);
      :_FillValue = -999.0f; // float
      :name = "PET";
      :long_name = "Potential evapotranspiration";
      :units = "mm";
      :standard_name = "PET";      

  :var_name = "PET";
}
```

What I tried to do was was use groupby to calculate monthly averages:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset("c:\\test\\Combined.nc")
ds_avg = ds.PET.groupby('time.month').mean(dim='time')
ds_avg.to_netcdf("C:\\test\\Combined_avg.nc")
```

But the problem with above code is spits out a file with combined monthly average (from 2011 to 2015). That means i have 12 months in the result file. That is not what i want to do. I want to calculate the monthly average for January 2011, Feb 2011, March 2011 to Dec 2015 so that i get 12 * 5 months in the result file. So that means that the groupby should happen not on 'time.month' but 'time.year:time.month'. How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `resample`[doc](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html) with the frequency with one month. Then:

```
ds_avg = ds.resample('1M').mean()
```

If you are interested on any other similar (simple) manipulations have a look at this notebook we have set up for the [ERA-NUTS dataset](https://github.com/energy-modelling-toolkit/era-nuts-code/blob/master/notebooks/exploring-ERA-NUTS.ipynb).

Another example using another dataset:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (bnds: 2, latitude: 61, longitude: 91, time: 218)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -22.5 -21.75 -21.0 -20.25 ... 43.5 44.25 45.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 72.0 71.25 70.5 69.75 ... 28.5 27.75 27.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-16T15:00:00 ... 2018-01-01T03:00:00
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    time_bnds  (time, bnds) datetime64[ns] ...
    ssrdc      (time, latitude, longitude) float64 ...
    ssrd       (time, latitude, longitude) float64 ...
```

And then applying the resample:

```
In [13]: d.resample(time = '1Y').mean()                                                                                           
Out[13]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 61, longitude: 91, time: 19)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-12-31 2001-12-31 ... 2018-12-31
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -22.5 -21.75 -21.0 -20.25 ... 43.5 44.25 45.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 72.0 71.25 70.5 69.75 ... 28.5 27.75 27.0
Data variables:
    ssrdc      (time, latitude, longitude) float64 5.033e+05 ... 1.908e+05
    ssrd       (time, latitude, longitude) float64 4.229e+05 ... 1.909e+05
```

Comment: That didn't quite work as expected. I expected the output PET variable to be of dimensions PET(time=60, latitude=681, longitude=841) where 60 is the number of months (monthly averages for 5 years). But what i got was PET(time=60) where the latitude and longitude dimensions are missing.

Comment: This is strange, are you doing any other operations like a groupby? Can you share your code?

Comment: # open 5 NetCDF files name PET_2011.nc, PET_2012.nc to PET_2015.nc
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(os.path.join("C:\\temp\\", 'PET_*.nc'))
ds_avg = ds.PET.resample(time='1M').mean()
ds_avg.to_netcdf("C:\\temp\\Combined_new_resample_avg.nc")

Comment: Can you check if xarray loads properly the data variables? Just a print of `ds`...

Comment: I have written a sample script here using a example dataset that comes out of the box. It shows that after resampling data and taking a mean, the result loses lat and lon dimensions: https://repl.it/repls/RareStaleRam

Comment: If i change your answer slightly by removing PET, it works: ds_avg = ds.resample('1M').mean(). So if you could please edit your answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: I have changed it, I wasn't aware of that different behaviour

Comment: Hey, I have same problem and when I try to do ds.resample('1M').mean() I'm getting:
ValueError: the first argument to .resample must be a dictionary
Do you know how can I do same problem with their latest update.

Comment: @Chris_007 Late to the party, but you need to say ds.resample(time='1M).mean()